# phonegap 3.4 can't close inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova

I have a phonegap/jQuery Mobile Android app that opens an external URL (which I can't modify its contents) using `window.open(URL)`.

The problem is that I can't get it to close and return to the "normal" app, I get the following error in the logcat: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined", source: here_goes_the_external_url.html`

A little below the logcat shows: `"exception firing pause event from native", source: here_goes_the_external_url.html`

The thing is that I don't know if the cause is that I'm capturing the "back event" to control exactly what happens when the user presses it, I have this in my **onDeviceReady()** function: `document.addEventListener("backbutton", pressBackButton, false);`

Is there a way I can force the back button to close that window? It seems that once it opens that window **cordova** isn't active anymore (thus the undefined error), but isn't it the point of the inappbrowser, to open it **inside** the app?

And yes, I forgot to mention, I'm loading the inappbrowser plugin

Answer (score 1):

So looking for an answer I found another thread with a similar problem, and after investigating a bit I found a solution, which I posted as an answer in that other thread: [Handle Android Back Button on Phonegap InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569269/handle-android-back-button-on-phonegap-inappbrowser/23765846#23765846)

If someone else is looking for my answer, go to that link and look for the answer with my username

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

And add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**closebuttoncaption** closes it

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank'location=yes','closebuttoncaption=Done');
```